# Chilliad calculation discrepancy

Tags: c++, precision

I was wondering if someone could give me a quick assist on this one. I just finished my chilliad program. It calculates the primes and average number of primes. However, when I look at my answer and the teacher's answer, I seem to be off by like .5 in either direction.

She has:

Total primes in the first 50 chiliads: 5133
Average number per chiliad: 102.66

I have:

Total primes in the first 50 chiliads: 5134
Average number per chiliad: 102

I am somewhat sure it is because my answer is not rounding correctly but I tried showpoint setprecison and it didnt work :( Do you guys have any suggestions? I appreciate any help! Thanks! Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

const int CHILIADS = 50;

bool isPrime (long n);
long primeCount (long x, long y);

using namespace std;
int main()
{

    cout << setw(10) << left << "Start" << setw(10) << "End" << setw(24) << "Number of Primes" << endl;

    primeCount (0, 50000);

    return 0;
}

// Determines whether the number is prime
bool isPrime (long n)
{
    int a;

    if (n == 1)
    {
        return false;
    }

    for (a = 2; a <= (n / 2); a++)
    {
        if ((n % a) == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
    return true;
}

// Counts and organizes the prime numbers using the isPrime function
long primeCount (long x, long y)
{
    bool prime;
    int b;
    int c = 1000;
    int counter = 0;
    int totalSum = 0;

    for (b = x; b <= y; b++)
    {
        prime = isPrime (b);

        if (prime == true)
        {
            counter++;
        }
        if (b == c)
        {
            cout << setw(10) << left << (b - 999) << setw(10) << left << b << setw(12) << counter << endl;
            cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2) << endl;  
            totalSum = totalSum + counter;
            counter = 0;
            c = c + 1000;
        }
    }

    cout << endl << "Total primes in the first 50 chiliads: " << totalSum << endl;
    cout << "Average number per chiliad: " << totalSum / CHILIADS << endl;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
primeCount (0, 50000);

long primeCount (long x, long y)
{
...
    for (b = x; b <= y; b++)
```

Basically, you are counting 0 as a prime number.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I tweaked it accordingly and it is now working perfectly :)

Comment: What I ended up doing was on line 16, I changed 0 to 1 because 0 is not prime. Then, I added (double) to line 70. Lastly, I made b =1. That did the trick. Thanks for the tips! I left set precision in there because it did make my columns look neater :)